# I have a series but I want to split to the right of a comma to get the integer

Tags: python, dataframe

For example I have this

```
1   ['cancelled:', '7']
```

And I want to split to only get the integer value of 7. How can I go about this using str.split()?

Comment: Are you sure it's a string and not a list?

Comment: I can see a series not string. If your input is really a list, use list[0].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s.str.split(expand=True)`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['cancelled:', '7'])
a = s.str.split(expand = True)
print(int(a[0][1]))

> Output:
> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The split method returns a list. To get the second element of this list, the number, do `str.split(sep)[1]`, where "sep" is the separator you use.

If your list contains various couples of elements like `["cancelled:", "7", "accepted", "19"]`, you can get all the elements of the list with uneven index, using a `range(1, len(list), 2)`:

```
your_list = string.split(sep)
your_list = [your_list[i] for i in range(1, len(your_list), 2)]
```